# Hide only params of a link on browser's statusbar, mouseover on links on webpage?

Tags: jsp, url, statusbar

I don't want to hide the total url, But i just want to hide the params of the hyperlink and values of the params on the status bar of the webpage when mouseover.
In banking sites,I experienced showing very big not understandable url in status bar?
How to acheive them?

Comment: Please tell the reason while downvoting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the pararms to show in the url you have to submit them by POST.

This may not help you in case you are using linkText, but will work in case on form submit.

Be aware that in case of the page being refreshed you will get a message from the browser saying that it has to send the information again.

Another option you have is using frames. Just declare a frame in your html and navigate only inside the frame. Your url will not change, but in this case you will have troubles when the user wants to bookmark the page.

Hope it helps